# Getting a:hover to adjust more than one class/id

Tags: css, menu, hover, background-position, nav

Been struggling with getting something to work and I've looked a bunch of places already, any help greatly appreciated.

Basically I have a nav menu that is made up of a few rollover images (normal state 'left top', hover state 'left bottom', they are currently configured to rollover upon over individually via css - these look like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="archives">Archives</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="about">About</a></li>
</ul>

#menu {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 24.6em;
width: 79em;
position: relative;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
text-indent: -900%;
position: absolute;
outline: none;
}


#menu a:hover {
background-position: left bottom;}


#menu .home {
width: 520px;
height: 124px;
background: url(images/Home Menu.png) no-repeat;
left: 0px;
top: 122px;
}

#menu .archives {
width: 263px;
height: 57px;
background: url(images/Archives Menu.png) no-repeat;
left: 0px;
top: 189px;
}

and so on for the rest of the links.
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve, is to have all of them roll over when I hover any of them. So say I hovered over "archives"; the following would roll over "archives, contact, about"

I've already tried the following and it didn't work (the opacity clause did exactly what I wanted it to do, but for some reason this doesn't seem to work for "background-position"):

```
#menu:hover .archives {background-position: left bottom; opacity: 0.5}
#menu:hover .contact {background-position: left bottom; opacity: 0.5}
#menu:hover .about {background-position: left bottom; opacity: 0.5}
```

How would I go about achieving this? thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohnno,

You were on the right track, but its not working due to specificity requirements. Try going this route:

```
#menu:hover a { background-position: left bottom; opacity:0.5; }
```

If it is still not working, try:

```
#menu:hover li a { background-position: left bottom; opacity:0.5; }
```

Finally, you may also apply an !important to the rule to enforce the  rule. !important is a special flag for CSS that tells the browser "This overrides whatever you may think" (kinda).Here is an example:

```
#menu:hover li a { background-position: left bottom !important; opacity:0.5; }
```

For more information on specificity, check out [this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) at the W3C. In short, specificity defines which styles are used at which times. Applied Element Style is defined, on a rule by rule, by the style with highest specificity for each of the styles that may apply.

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. that's brilliant! works like a charm. thanks many

Comment: Thanks much. Glad I was able to help. W3C is a pain to read but it has a LOT of info that many skip over when learning CSS from any other source. (It's also extremely dry).

Answer (score 0):

`left-bottom` may not be changing enough so you don't notice the change. try right?

Comment: If you read the CSS, the background-position does not apply to the menu. Additionally, you are assuming that he has no style defined in his HTML. If he defines the background-image in his HTML, the background-position would indeed apply.